# Installation of ubuntu on a windows 7 machine using virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am trying to install the lastest version of ubuntu in my windows 7 machine using virtual box. I have been following this [example](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox). Virtual box has created a new partition within my `C: Drive` for 8 gb. I was able to mount the ubunto iso using virtual box. Now when I try to install Ubuntu, It shows `Ubuntu will be installed in the following drive and all the contents in it will be deleted`. I wanna know does the installation would happen within the 8 gb space or would it format my C: Drive?

Answer (score 3):

If you create a virtual hard disk (your 8GB spacer) this acts like a normal
hard drive. So the warning is completely normal.
For the guest OS (the ubuntu you are trying to install) the virtual machine acts like a normal computer. 
And like on a real computer it's going to ask wether you want to format the drive or not.

**Conclusion:** you cans safely format because you're formatting the virtual harddrive (disk file) and not your real physical one.